# Profile provder to limiting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-profiles

I am developing an app using .net mvc 2 c#. 
I am using the built in membership and profiling framework of ASP.NET 2.0. 
I have how run into a big problem. My profile provider has many properties, and I want to build a dynamic search feature of my members, using their profiles as filters. 
This is a big problem because of the serialized way that profile data is stored - I'm not going to be able to be able to perform linq queries on this data.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I should do?

I want to keep the membership api and sqlMembershipProvider, but want to also develop a custom table to hold my profile data?

Can any one point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using the [SQL Table Profile Provider in ASP.NET 4 Web Applications](http://weblogs.asp.net/kencox/archive/2010/09/05/using-the-sql-table-profile-provider-in-asp-net-4-web-applications-c-amp-vb.aspx)